# Conditionally fire ItemClick

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime

I have a ListView populated with items that should perform actions when tapped, but only when tapped on certain areas:

XAML:

```
<ListView
  SelectionMode="None"
  IsItemClickEnabled="True"
  ItemClick="MyListView_ItemClick">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <custom:MyListViewItemControl Tapped="ListViewItem_Tapped"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Code-behind:

```
private void MyListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource is Image) return; // Ignore if clicked on Image
    if (this.ItemClickHandler != null)
    {
         this.ItemClickHandler(this, e);
    }
}
```

In this code, the `e.OriginalSource` is always the `ListView`, so the approach of checking the type of the `OriginalSource` does not work.

I can also use the `Tapped` event on individual ListView items, but this changes the type of events received (to `TappedRoutedEventArgs`), so I'll have to change my handler signature all the way up the stack, which I'd like to avoid if possible.  (I can't just make a new `ItemClickEventArgs` because there's no way to set its values that I can see, and it's a sealed class so I can't subclass it.)

Comment: If you're putting objects in the ItemTemplate individually that are supposed to receive the event instead of the whole item, you can just add `ClickMode="Pressed"` to those objects and they'll take their own events instead of getting hijacked by the parent items click event. That is, provided I'm understanding what you're shooting for correctly.

Comment: @ChrisW. I'm not sure where you're suggesting I add the `ClickMode` attribute.  Intellisense tells me it's not defined for both ListView and my custom ListView item control (which inherits from `UserControl`).

Comment: So when I read the part about only wanting certain areas of an item to respond to certain click events, to me I'm thinking you're putting buttons or something inside of the ItemTemplate of the ListView, is that correct or no?

Comment: I'm listening for `ItemClick` events from the `ListView` object.  There are parts of the `ListView` items that have different types of UI elements (not necessarily buttons), which I want to filter on, but still handle with the `ItemClick` event.